# this.props.navigation.setParams() doesn't updates parameters from navigation which were passed previously

Tags: react-native, components, react-navigation, react-component, react-native-tabnavigator

I am using a `TabNavigator` in my react-native project, and pass some data between the screens via `this.props.navigation.setParams()`, and respectively `this.props.navigation.getParam()`. The problem is that this approach works for me, only when I send that data for the first time, second time when I try to send the data, when leaving the screen the data doesn't update in `navigation.state.params`

Here are fragments of code responsible for receiving, and sending data

```
import {NavigationEvents} from 'react-navigation';

...

receiveData = () => {
    if (this.props.navigation.state.params.data !== null) {
        const data = this.props.navigation.getParam('data');
        this.setState({data});
    }
}

sendData = () => {
    const {data} = this.state;
    this.props.navigation.setParams({data});
}

render(){

...

<NavigationEvents
    onWillFocus = {this.receiveData}
    on WillBlur = {this.sendData}
/>

...

}
```

Comment: be careful with the use of `setParams()`, it's a asynchronous task that may take enought time to apply that a `console.log()` right after it could miss it

Comment: So you suggest that I should make the functions async, and trigger the `setParams()` with `await` keyword in front?

Comment: no simply set your data like this : `this.props.navigation.state.params.data` and then use the `setParams()` right after to make sure it stays

Answer (score 0):

check if the tabnavigator is blurring/focusing your tab properly.

Answer (score 0):

Put the method `sendData()` inside `render()` function of your component, it's the only way that will allow you to update the parameter.